# Installation of memsql on mac

Tags: mysql, boot2docker, singlestore

How to install memsql on mac. I have tried installing it with boot2docker but there are some errors. If anyone have the minimum requirements or step by step installation it would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

What errors are you seeing?

On the MemSQL docs, you can find a step-by-step guide for setting up MemSQL using Docker: http://docs.memsql.com/4.0/setup/docker/

To install boot2docker, I'd recommend using Homebrew. Then with a few lines you can install Virtualbox and boot2docker.

For more information about setting up MemSQL on-prem, see: http://docs.memsql.com/latest/setup/setup_onprem/

For more information about setting up MemSQL on AWS using a generated CloudFormation template from cloud.memsql.com, see:
http://docs.memsql.com/latest/setup/setup_cloud/

Comment: I have installed boot2docker, do I need mysql also to run memsql, sorry if its a basic doubt

Comment: FATA[0000] Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.18/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS? .This is the following error its showing

Comment: Ah. That's a boot2docker configuration.
Try running $(boot2docker shellinit) , then try running the command again

Comment: Thank you. I am done with the installation of memsql. I have create a memsql cluster of 3 different ec2 instances as nodes. I have tried creating cluster using cloudmemsql, The three instances have same key pair value. How can I build a cluster now? I am new to using aws also. If I am fundamentally wrong please correct me.

Answer (score 1):

**Steps to install memsql in mac**

Run the following commands in the terminal:

1. `xcode-select --install`
2. `sudo -H pip install mysql-python`
3. `sudo -H pip install memsql --ignore-installed six`